# How to setup authentication for Salesforce service

Tags: python, oauth, salesforce

I'm building a python service that syncs data with Salesforce in both directions. To use the service, each user will have to authorise his own Salesforce account.

I've looked at Heroku Connect, but it doesn't seem to support a scenario where many different accounts can automatically be connected. Then looking at the API examples I noticed that almost always there is a user account as well as a password used in the request.

Being used to Gmail's APIs, I'm thinking if it is really necessary to ask for and save the user's password, or if there is another way to authenticate the requests. Requests will typically be initiated by the backend at random moments.

There's so much available from Salesforce that I am not sure where to start. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the OAuth Web Flow to enable your app to make requests on behalf of a user.  There is a Python utility to help with that: https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-oauth-request

Comment: So that means that the user will always also have to pass me his password for the initial signup? But as it looks I won't have to store it, correct?

Comment: You app never gets a password with OAuth.  Salesforce gives you an auth token: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm

Comment: Ah I see, the username and password in the code are my own. Good, yes this is what I was expecting / looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I only use password auth when doing machine-to-machine integration.

Comment: Is there a library you would recommend to run the actual request once I've authorized? I looked into simple-salesforce but it doesnt seem to support the auth token scenario if I understood correctly.

Comment: I think simple-salesforce is the only one and it should definitely support the OAuth Web Flow.  But I haven't personally tried it.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I will look into it in more detail. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88568/discussion-between-vincent-and-james-ward).